# Android localization: strings resource file valid for all languages

Tags: android, string, localization, app-store, android-resources

My Android app is localized in some different languages. However it needs some strings to be the same for all languages and they cannot be different, so there cannot be any mistake.

I thought that those particular strings should be not localized so I used common_strings.xml but I see that I have to copy the common_strings.xml file in each values folder.

I would like to have a xml string resource file that is “really” common amongst languages, I cannot believe it is not possible.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it.

By default Android Studio uses `values/strings.xml`, so if some strings are missing - let's say in German translation, it would get them from this default location.

This may also help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Any question? Please free to ask

Hope it help